# "Modify Launch Template Version" option is showing as "Set Default version" while trying to create new launch template version

Tags: amazon-web-services, launch-template

I have been seeing this issue since last few days, while trying to create a new launch template version in the Actions section instead of the **Modify Launch Template** option I am seeing the **Set Default version** option twice.

This appears to be a UI issue because when I click on the '**Set Default Version**' option where the '**Modify Launch Template Version**' option used to be, it still opens the expected page. The only problem is that the name is displaying incorrectly. I've attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqr7l.png) to illustrate how it appears for me.